# how to change domain name in aws?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am new to Amazon AWS EC2. I have setup a wordpress blog on the EC2 instance. Everything is fine except the ugly looking domain name. `ec2-xx-xx-143-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

How can I change this `ec2-xx-xx-143-xxx.us-west-2.compute` to something like `tintinnotes.amazonws.com`

Pl. not that I don't want to buy a domain name for this `tintinnotes.com`, I just want an aliasing of instance name to my blog name just like wordpress has something like `tintinnotes.wordpress.com`

Update: I now have got a domain name registered with name `techweblogs.co.uk` from `fasthosts.co.uk`. Now I want to point the aws instance to this domain. How can I do this?

Comment: Amazon doesn't allow us (yet) to choose a sub-domain, like wordpress.com does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without buying a domain name it will not be possible for you to get rid of the amazon long Public Name. You cannot do aliasing to wordpress.com domain , even for that you require your own domain name.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks for the response, I have a domain name registered and I have updated the question. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Point your domain at your server's Elastic IP.

Comment: So so many free DNS services are available like dnsexit.com , register  on them and add ur domain there and create a hostname recors (A record) for your subdomian pointing to your IP of aws server., I would recommend add Elastic IP to your box instead of using Dynamic Public DNS .

Comment: Can you ref me to some detailed doc. as how to do it as I am new to this - Many thanks.

Comment: Go through this link http://www.ipserverone.info/domain-related/domain-registration/how-to-add-new-dns-record-at-dnsexit-name-server/

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I added the ip address to the dns and now I can access my wordpress site using dns name http://www.techweblogs.co.uk/ but I have lost all the CSS styling and all links in the page are pointing to ec2 instance (ec2-xx-xx-143-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com), what's going on here?

Comment: With AWS long Public name all your CSS loading fine?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change in EC2.  That being said, you can request Reverse DNS if trying to setup an email server.  Just create a A record pointed at your elastic IP.  This will essentially provide you that.  There are no custom subdomains like your describing in AWS.